# Center div over an img

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems positioning my div centrally containing a text over an image.

```css
.event-list img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.description {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card {
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="event-list">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/860/356?random=1" alt="banner" />
    <div class="description">
      <h3 class="event-title"> Event Title 1</h3>
      <p class="event-info"> Date: DD/MM/YYYY Time: HH:mm </p>
      <button class="button-primary"> Register </button>
      <button class="button-primary"> Learn More </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="event-list">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/860/356?random=2" alt="banner" />
    <div class="description">
      <h3 class="event-title"> Event Title 2</h3>
      <p class="event-info"> Date: DD/MM/YYYY Time: HH:mm </p>
      <button class="button-primary"> Register </button>
      <button class="button-primary"> Learn More </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matsom/4qxm8b2j/)

I'm trying to achieve each image with their own text description. The text is overlapped and unresponsive (it works on large screen)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Center horizontally and vertically?

Comment: both horizontally and vertically sir

Comment: @MatSom try with below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set position relative to `.event-list`

```
.event-list {
  position:relative;
}
```

```css
.event-list img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.description {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.description h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.card {
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}
.event-list {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="event-list">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/860/356?random=1" alt="banner" />
    <div class="description">
      <h3 class="event-title"> Event Title 1</h3>
      <p class="event-info"> Date: DD/MM/YYYY Time: HH:mm </p>
      <button class="button-primary"> Register </button>
      <button class="button-primary"> Learn More </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="event-list">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/860/356?random=2" alt="banner" />
    <div class="description">
      <h3 class="event-title"> Event Title 2</h3>
      <p class="event-info"> Date: DD/MM/YYYY Time: HH:mm </p>
      <button class="button-primary"> Register </button>
      <button class="button-primary"> Learn More </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tick this answer if its use full to you

Comment: sorry, but its seem im having less that 15 reputation and i can't upvote this

Comment: done, anyway, do you have any ideas if I make the screen smaller then the text will start to overflow from the images

Comment: Yes , you can use `media quieries` like `@media(max-width:375px){ /*do somthing here*/}` you can reduce the font size margin padding etc

Answer (score 0):

Just add `position:relative` to `.card`, so that `.description` will know where it is relative to.

```
.card {
      position: relative;
      // rest of style
 }
```

```css
.event-list img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.description {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="event-list">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/860/356?random=1" alt="banner" />
    <div class="description">
      <h3 class="event-title"> Event Title 1</h3>
      <p class="event-info"> Date: DD/MM/YYYY Time: HH:mm </p>
      <button class="button-primary"> Register </button>
      <button class="button-primary"> Learn More </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="event-list">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/860/356?random=2" alt="banner" />
    <div class="description">
      <h3 class="event-title"> Event Title 2</h3>
      <p class="event-info"> Date: DD/MM/YYYY Time: HH:mm </p>
      <button class="button-primary"> Register </button>
      <button class="button-primary"> Learn More </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot

`.event-list {
   position: relative;
}`

Answer (score 0):

you need is only give your `.card` a position: relative

```css
.card{
  position: relative;
}
.event-list img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.description {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card {
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="event-list">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/860/356?random=1" alt="banner" />
    <div class="description">
      <h3 class="event-title"> Event Title 1</h3>
      <p class="event-info"> Date: DD/MM/YYYY Time: HH:mm </p>
      <button class="button-primary"> Register </button>
      <button class="button-primary"> Learn More </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="event-list">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/860/356?random=2" alt="banner" />
    <div class="description">
      <h3 class="event-title"> Event Title 2</h3>
      <p class="event-info"> Date: DD/MM/YYYY Time: HH:mm </p>
      <button class="button-primary"> Register </button>
      <button class="button-primary"> Learn More </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set position relative to class `.card` or `.event-list`.